# MS Word RegEx capitalizing letters after a special character

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I am trying to write a VBA macro for MS Word 2010 that capitalizes letters after a special character. In my case an underscore "_". The words that I want to revise, start with a special prefix. I am having trouble with the replace operation. I am using Microsoft Regular Expression Library 5.5.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub ReplaceFunc()
'
' ReplaceFunc Macro
'
'
    Debug.Print ("entered replaceFunc")

    Dim myRegex As New RegExp
    myRegex.Global = True
    myRegex.IgnoreCase = False
    myRegex.MultiLine = True

'   i want to find all words in the document which start with BlaBlub and have a suffix like _foo_bar or _foo_bar_foo
'   e.g. BlaBlub_foo_bar, BlaBlub_foo_foo_bar_bar, BlaBlub_foo_bar_foo    
    myRegex.Pattern = "\bBlaBlub(_([a-z])+)+\b"

'   works i get the results i was looking for    
    Set Matches = myRegex.Execute(ActiveDocument.Range.Text)

'   now i want to capitalize every letter after a "_", e.g. BlaBlub_foo_bar --> BlaBlub_Foo_Bar    
    For Each Match In Matches
'   The idea is to run a new RegEx on every found substring but this time with replace
        Dim mySubRegex As New RegExp
        mySubRegex.Global = True
        mySubRegex.IgnoreCase = False
        mySubRegex.MultiLine = True
'   Matching every underscore followed by a non capital letter        
        mySubRegex.Pattern = "_([a-z])"

'   getting start and endindex from the match to run the regex only on the found word
        startIndex = Match.FirstIndex
        endIndex = (Match.FirstIndex + Match.Length)

'   where it fails with a syntax error        
        mySubRegex.Replace(ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=startIndex, End:=endIndex).Text , "_\u$1")

    Next

    Debug.Print ("leaving replaceFunc")


End Sub
```

The VBA macro fails with a syntax error in the line:

```
mySubRegex.Replace(ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=startIndex, End:=endIndex).Text , "_\u$1")
```

I am out of ideas, what to do to get it working. Can you point out what my error is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to correct, just suppress parentheses:

```
mySubRegex.Replace(ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=startIndex, End:=endIndex).Text , "_\u$1")
```

=>

```
mySubRegex.Replace ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=startIndex, End:=endIndex).Text , "_\u$1"
```

Or

```
Dim varVal
varVal = mySubRegex.Replace(ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=startIndex, End:=endIndex).Text , "_\u$1")
```

Comment: Ah right, this makes sense. But this doesn't seem to be the only problem in the script. The startIndex doesnt point where i would expect it. If i do Debug.Print (ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=startIndex, End:=endIndex).Text) i dont get the same als with Debug.Print (Match.Value). How is this possible?